# Using two props in a component

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, reactjs

I want to use two props in the grap_test component, one prop comes from a test.js component and the other comes from App.js. I have made a attempt where in graph_test.js i call them and use them in a temporary example to see if they are getting passed through.
However it says:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

on the 17 line of graph_test.

Does annybody have any suggestions?

Graph_Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from "jquery";
//<h1>{props.testing.map}</h1>
const Graph_Test = props => { 
    return(
      <div>
      <div>
      {props.testing.map((item, idx) => { 
        return (
          <label key={idx}>
            <input className="region" type="radio" value={idx} />
            <span>{idx}</span> 
          </label>
        );
      })}  
      </div><div>
      <h1>{props.array[0]}</h1>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  };export default Graph_Test;
```

Test

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from "jquery";
import Graph_Test from "./Graph_Test.js";
const Test = props => {
  const total_regions = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.test)).length); // gets the number of regions
  var ROI = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < total_regions.length; i++) { // Array to represent which regions need to be displayed
    ROI[i] = 0; // deault setting all regions equal 1 as must be displayed
  }
  //when a radio button is clicked change its corresponding in the array 
  const handleClick = (item, idx) => {
    if(ROI[idx] == 1){ // if region displayed and clicked -> undisplay region 
      ROI[idx] = 0; 
    }else{ // if region not displayed and clicked -> display region 
        ROI[idx] = 1; 
    }
    console.log(`Array ${ROI[idx]} with index ${idx} clicked`); // Used to test functionality of array 
  };

  return (
    // displays radio buttons depending on the number of objects in json
    <div>
    <div>
    {props.test.map((item, idx) => { 
      return (
        <label key={idx}>
          <input className="region" type="radio" value={idx} onClick={() => handleClick(item, idx)}/>
          <span>{idx}</span> 
        </label>
      );
    })}  
    </div>
    <div>
    <Graph_Test array = {ROI}/>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Test;
```

App.js

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import React from "react";
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import LeftPane from "./components/LeftPane.js";
import Video from "./components/Video.js";
//import Footer from "./components/Footer.js";
import Test from "./components/Test.js";
import Graph_Test from "./components/Graph_Test.js";
//import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { apiResponse: [] };

  }
  // Comunicate with API
  callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/IntensityAPI") //React app talks to API at this url
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.callAPI();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div class="row fixed-top fixed-bottom no-gutters"  >
            <div class="col-3 fixed-top fixed-bottom">
              <LeftPane></LeftPane>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-md-3 fixed-top fixed-bottom" >
              <Video></Video>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-3 fixed-bottom">
              <Graph_Test testing = {this.state.apiResponse}/>
              <Test test = {this.state.apiResponse}/>
            </div>      
            </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is in function component you don't have `this`. You were trying to use with `this.props.testing.map()`. Try to remove `this` which most probably solves the issue.

Instead try as the following:

```
return <div>
      {props.testing && props.testing.map((item, idx) => { 
        return (
          <label key={idx}>
            <input className="region" type="radio" value={idx} />
            <span>{idx}</span> 
          </label>
        );
      })}  
      </div><div>
      <h1>{props.array[0]}</h1>
</div>
```

**+1 suggestion after question has been updated:**

I have extended my solution for `null` or `undefined` checks with `&&`. If you add `props.testing && props.testing.map()` then you won't have the error what you face in the second problem.

Also one good solution is you need to pass `testing` as well once you use the component:

```
<Graph_Test array={ROI} testing={[]} /> { /* passing testing with [] */ }
```

Or passing array with `[]`:

```
<Graph_Test testing={this.state.apiResponse} array={[]} />
```

You need to have both `props` with default values or checking for `undefined` or `null` values in the `<Graph_Test />` component.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, i fixed that but i am still receiving an error. I have updated the post.

Comment: @Sue But now you removed the original problem from your question. The current one is related to `props.testing` is `undefined`, I have extended my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: just one more thing its giving me array ×
**TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Graph_Test** as I want to access an element in the array i do props.array[0] however is there something wrong with this?

Comment: Oh i think it works when i added your point in ur last comment thanks

Comment: how will i be sure it doesnt pass a empty array instead of the updated array, as nothing is  currently printing out for the array, do you think because its getting passed as a empty array?

Comment: @Sue Usually I use `console.log()` steps to check further which values I have in the code. Also it is worth to use the mentioned `null` check with `&&`.

Comment: Yeah I just used console.log() there and it says undefined, how would i check for null when calling the props.array?

Comment: I would try with `{ props.array && props.array.length > 0 && <h1>{props.array[0]}</h1> }`. With this way it only prints the `<h1>` and its content when you have at least one item in your array.

Comment: Thank you! and for when I use props in the Test component do I also have to apply this approach

Comment: hi @norbitrial ive a new problem but on the same code, could u have a look at for me its my newest question. As you were very helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211435/discussion-between-sue-and-norbitrial).

Answer (score 1):

In your first file, you reference this.props, but 'this' doesn't exit in a functional component. Just remove it

Comment: Thanks i've fixed that , but i am still receiving a error i've updated the post.

Comment: In App.js, you do <Graph_Test testing = {this.state.apiResponse}/> but then in Graph_Test you reference props.test which doesn't exist. Make sure the props have the same name